# Why is timeout occurring while executing a stored procedure in C# even after increasing the commandtimeout property?

Tags: c#, sql, executereader, command-timeout

I have a piece of code that executes stored procedure.i have given a "Waitfor Delay '00:05' " in the SP for the purpose of testing the timeout in my C# code wherein my commandtimeout is set for 10 mins. While debugging, after 20 seconds or so when the executereader for the SP is executed,I am getting a timeout .
Stuck on this for 2 days, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: add your code in question so will check, where is set `CommandTimeout` in your code.

Comment: Is it a connection timeout or a command timeout? Please show code

Answer (score 0):

Give ConnectionTimeout as 0, it means undefined waiting time.And one more thing , u can debug the SP using EXEC command in sql server itself and check where the time taking in code or in SP.

Connection Timout in code

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, ConnectionString);
da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

Execute SP in sql server

```
EXEC procedure_name;
```

Regards
Aravind

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).